# Textfield in tableview cell crashes on iOS7

Tags: iphone, ipad, uitableview, ios7, uitextfield

My code is working fine on iOS6 but crashing in iOS7.

I comparing the text field with table view cell text-field.

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{

    DLog(@"-> %@", textField.text);

    PhotoViewCustomCell *cell = (PhotoViewCustomCell*)[[textField superview] superview];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [tblPhotoDetail indexPathForCell:cell];

    //PhotoViewCustomCell *cell = (PhotoViewCustomCell *)[tblPhotoDetail cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    PhotoInformation *objPhotoInfo = [selectedPhotos objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    if ([textField isEqual:cell.mytextfield]) 
    { =========>crashing in this line

       do something
    }
    else 
    {
      do something
    }
}
```

**Error**:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITableViewCellScrollView mytextfield]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xdc119a0'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add additional superview call to get your cell. Looks like you are getting hidden UITableViewCellScrollView which goes in hierarchy immediately above contentView

```
 PhotoViewCustomCell *cell = (PhotoViewCustomCell*)[[[textField superview] superview] superview];
```

Answer (score 2):

The code in Accepted Answer is not the safer one and also can't be used for `iOS 6`. I'd rather recommend you to use this code. :

```
UIView *view = [textField superview];
while (![view isKindOfClass:[PhotoViewCustomCell class]]) {
    view = [view superview];
}
PhotoViewCustomCell *cell = (PhotoViewCustomCell *)view;
```